# upload image to a folder with model's title name django

Tags: django, attributeerror

I am a newbie in django and I want to upload image in an `ImageField` to folder with the name of the title which is retrieved by a `CharField` and I get this error on the 8th line while trying to `makemigrations`:

> AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'model'

Here's the code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Starter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = ArrayField(models.ImageField(upload_to='starter/{}'.format(title)), size=10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title', 'price',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Your code would try to evaluate `upload_to` at class definition time, when there's no instance title. You have to write a callable `upload_to` that can access the instance title at runtime instead. See the duplicate question for how to do that.